# How can I install Windows 10 to a folder not called Windows?

Tags: windows-10

In the past (before Windows XP), I could install Windows NT to a folder with custom name (not named `Windows` in case of Windows XP, or `WINNT` in case of Windows 2000 or before) by tweaking the installation ini. This was preserved if I upgrade Windows XP to Windows Vista or later.

However, is there a method to perform a clean installation of Windows 10 (or any version of Windows Vista or later) such that it installs into a folder not name Windows? e.g. installing Windows to `F:\ThisIsFunny`?

Comment: No - attempting to do so would break a multitude of hard links required for system operation.  It is possible to create a junction link for `%ProgramFiles%` & `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, and you may be able to do the same with `%WinDir%`, however should something ever cause the target of those links to become unavailable, Windows wouldn't boot and you'll spend a bit of time in WinRE or [WinPE SE](http://win10se.cwcodes.net/) either figuring out where the issue lies or correcting the issue.  Generally speaking, it's better to conform to the OS system directory structure than attempt to customize it.

Comment: So how is it different if I upgrade a Windows XP installation at `F:\ThisIsFunny` to Windows Vista, then 7, then 8, 8.1 and 10, such that the Windows 10 installation will remain at `F:\ThisIsFunny`? If Windows 10 can work properly here, it should also be able to work properly if done as a clean installation.

Comment: Windows isn't designed like that and you will likely run into issues doing so, as the OS and software expects `%WinDir%`||`$WinDir` to point to `C:\Windows`. Things might work or they might not, I don't know since it's not the way Microsoft intended Windows to be configured - it's best to follow the developer's implementation rather than trying to arbitrarily customize something hardcoded like `C:\Windows`. It would also be a very bad idea to upgrade 8.1 and under to Windows 10 or higher due to OEM drivers resulting in BSODs, which is why clean installing is always recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is a wee bit different than Windows NT4.  You cannot change the name of the folder (or Program Files, Program Data). You can install to a different drive but C: remains best.

Windows 10 can do a variety of Repair Installs and also keep Windows.old for feature upgrades.

So it needs to know where everything is and changing folder locations could screw that up badly.